# Why does model.losses return regularization losses?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I have met a snippet of code of tensorflow 2.0, which is used for calculating the loss. The total loss is composed of two parts: 1) regularization loss, 2) prediction loss. My question is why `model.losses` is regularization loss? `model` here is an instance of `tf.keras.Model`. I'm kind of confused by the tensorflow official API documentation. [tf.keras.Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#losses), it says

> Losses which are associated with this Layer.
>
> Variable regularization tensors are created when this property is accessed, so it is eager safe: accessing losses under a `tf.GradientTape` will propagate gradients back to the corresponding variables.

Why could we get regularization loss via accessing `losses` property? Also, what is eager safe? If `losses` property is returning regularization loss, why is it named `losses` instead of `regularization_loss`?

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  outputs = model(images, training=True)
  regularization_loss = tf.reduce_sum(model.losses)
  pred_loss = ...
  total_loss = pred_loss + regularization_loss
```

Answer (score 7):

We get regularization losses accessing the `losses` property because these losses are created during the model definition. Since the model is a Keras model, you've built it using Keras layers. Every Keras layer (Dense, Conv3D, ...) can be regularized and this is a property of the layer itself.

The model, being an ordered collection of layers, contains all the layers losses inside the `losses` property.

Eager safe means you can use the `losses` property of the model during the eager training, being sure that the gradient is propagated only to the correct layers. E.g. if you added an l2 regularization only on the second layer of a model, the variables of the second layer only are influenced (and updated) by that term of the loss.

Is named `losses` instead of `regularization_losses` because is not limited to regularization losses only; when you compile a model, a non-regularization loss is added to that property